# Calculating percentage of property perimeter affected by flooding (excluding internal walls) using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop

I am trying to determine the percentage of a polygon perimeter that is intersected by another.

In short, I am carrying out some flooding analysis in ArcGIS 10 and am trying to determine properties that

1. are directly affected by the flood mapping and
2. the percentage of a property's perimeter that is affected excluding any internal walls.

I'm using Ordnance survey master map data for building polygons.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your first question just needs the Select Layer By Location tool.  It is the second one that I think should be the focus of this Question.  To answer that I think we may need a diagram to distinguish whether you are talking about walls internal to building(s) on the property from walls which run internal to but attached to the perimeter.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Essentially, I'm trying to determine the wetted perimeter of a property based on flood mapping. Where this would be straight forward enough for a detached property, where the property is terraced, there will always be an adjoining internal wall which needs to be removed when calculating the total affected permimeter.

Comment: Do you have access to high resolution DEM data (e.g. <10m)?  Perhaps you already have a polygon of the flood extent.  In this case, you can do a Union of the two layers and make the calculations via the attribute table.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. For the comparison I'm using a flood map polygon generated using Lidar data etc. and building outline polygons. Do you think the union will overcome the issue of the internal wall where 2 or more buildings are joined together?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to achieve this:

wetted perimeter of a property A = 7 meters

wetted perimeter of a property B = 10 meters
[image]

I would try this appoach:

1. Use [Clip (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Clip/000800000004000000/) to cut out the part of the buildings which overlap with flood
2. Calculate length of Perimeter
3. Use [Polygon Neighbors (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/na/000800000045000000/) to calculate the length of coincident edges (edge neighbors).
4. Use result of  (2) and (3)  to calculate wetted perimeter.

Perhaps you have to add some work steps (Join, [Summary Statistics (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Summary_Statistics/00080000001z000000/)).

---

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I noticed that this approach provides the wrong length. I do not delete my answer. Maybe someone can further develop the approach so that it works.
[image]